# after fitting a new light, it will not turn off at the switch, my wiring is brown, blue ang yellow/green

Tags: ceiling, light, fitting

I never took a picture of how the previous fitting was connected. However there are three grey cables, each containing a brown, a blue and yellow/green. the earth wires are connected together, has are the brown ones, but the blue are not connected, and I don't know which wire goes to the connection blocks

Comment: More information is needed: how many switches operate the same lights? Normaly brown is Line=hot=Phase, blue is Neutral and yellow/green is Protection Earth. But with multiple switches involved, this can be different. Normally the blue ones are connected, the brown ones are switched. Her it seems to be the contrary. Photos of the backside of the switches and lamps are very helpful.

Comment: ... f.e. a 3 way switch would toggle the incoming Line to 2 separate parallel wires (=cable no 1), i.e. both brown and blue could be (switched) Line. Neutral could come in from another cable, f.e. from cable no 2.

Comment: If you're new to this,  please have someone experienced or licensed fix it for you.  And for goodness' sake, next time take photos or make detailed wiring diagrams **before** starting any work!

Comment: This happens a lot with Euro power because the lovely, logical 8-screw lug block is often part of the lamp rose, and so people change it when they change the lamp.  The lug block is basically two 3-screw Alumiconns and one 2-screw in one unit.